# SwiftyJSON: Calling segue but connection tries fetching data

Tags: json, swift

My ViewController is set to update JSON data on a server. That works perfectly. But when I set my VC to perform a segue back to another segue it crashes with the following statement:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This happens at this line:

```
let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSArray
```

The error happens on the "UpdateVC" and the segue points to "ListVC".

Comment: it is occuring because you are wrapping a nil value using `!` some value in your json is nil have you checked your data properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ending part of that statement is doing a forced unwrapping:

```
as! NSArray
```

since it throws an exception, it means that either:

- the return value is `nil`
- the return value cannot be cast to `NSArray`

I can't say what the correct way to handle that would be, because it depends on your app logic. If the cast should (ideally) always succeed, then you probably have a bug in your app. On the other hand, if it's possible that the cast doesn't succeed, then the best way is to protect that with an optional binding:

```
if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSArray {
    // do something
}
```